# Multiple paths to the same server share

Tags: windows

I would like to use two paths to the same share, for example

```
\\server\share
```

and

```
\\test\share
```

I have a DNS entry for both names pointing to the servers IP but only one resolves, the additional name 'test' in this case doesn't work I get the error "the target account name is incorrect".

Why would this be?

Comment: Can you ping "test" and get a response with the right IP? If not your DNS is likely at fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that the one that works is the one that uses the Computer Name of the server in question, and I'm also guessing that your two entries are both Host (A) records.

Firstly you need to delete the A record that relates to the second name ("test") and recreate it as an Alias (CNAME) record pointing to the original Host (A) record for "server".  Then you need to read [the following KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281308) and implement the steps outlined in it (don't worry that the symptoms as described are different to your's, it is the same thing).

Comment: You're spot on, I'd created an (A) record and not a CNAME record. Thanks mh